# Combinations with divisibility

Tags: combinations

How many 4 digit numbers, which are not divisible by 5 can be formed  using the digits 4,5,6,7 without repeating any digit?

I have tried by using this formula `nPr` my answer is 24? is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. If we permute the 4 digits we get 4! = 24 possibilities, but some of these possibilities have 5 in the units place i.e. are divisible by 5. I believe you should get 18

Answer (score 1):

The total number of combinations is $4!=24$.

The number of combinations ending with $5$ is $3!=6$.

The number of combinations not ending with $5$ is $24-6=18$.

Answer (score 0):

Or to see it a third way.  There are 3 possible choices for the last digit, a:4,6,and 7.  There are 3 possible chosen for the third digit, b: the three that aren't a.  There are 2 choices for the second digit, c: the two that aren't a or b.  There is one chose for the first digit: whatever is left.

So there are $3*3*2*1=18$ possible ways to do this.